# Maximum likelihood estimation for custom equation in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, nonlinear-regression

For this non-linear equation

$$y = a\left(1-\exp\left(-\left(x/b\right)\right)\right)^c$$

by using least square estimated values for the parameters are obtained and

```
x <- c(3, 33, 146, 227, 342, 351, 353, 444, 556, 571, 709, 759, 836, 
860, 968, 1056, 1726, 1846, 1872, 1986, 2311, 2366, 2608, 2676, 
3098, 3278, 3288, 4434, 5034, 5049, 5085, 5089, 5089, 5097, 5324, 
5389, 5565, 5623, 6080, 6380, 6477, 6740, 7192, 7447, 7644, 7837, 
7843, 7922, 8738, 10089, 10237, 10258, 10491, 10625, 10982, 11175, 
11411, 11442, 11811, 12559, 12559, 12791, 13121, 13486, 14708, 
15251, 15261, 15277, 15806, 16185, 16229, 16358, 17168, 17458, 
17758, 18287, 18568, 18728, 19556, 20567, 21012, 21308, 23063, 
24127, 25910, 26770, 27753, 28460, 28493, 29361, 30085, 32408, 
35338, 36799, 37642, 37654, 37915, 39715, 40580, 42015, 42045, 
42188, 42296, 42296, 45406, 46653, 47596, 48296, 49171, 49416, 
50145, 52042, 52489, 52875, 53321, 53443, 54433, 55381, 56463, 
56485, 56560, 57042, 62551, 62651, 62661, 63732, 64103, 64893, 
71043, 74364, 75409, 76057, 81542, 82702, 84566, 88682)

y <- c(1:136)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

fit <- nls(y ~ a*(1-exp(-x/b))^c, data=df, start = list( a=100,b=1000,c=0.5),  
     algorithm="port",lower=list(a=100,b=100,c=0.5),upper=list(a=200,b=10000,c=2))
```

**How to do this using Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) for this non-linear equation?**

Comment: The function `mle` in the package `stats4` may help, but not certain.

Comment: Using MLE under what distributional assumption? You can't even write down a likelihood if there's no assumed distribution for $y$ at a given $x$ value.

Comment: If it is least-squares then implicitly the solution is the MLE for Gaussian distributed errors/residuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Least squares equals MLE for Gaussian distributed errors

'Minimizing the sum of least squares' **is equivalent to** 'maximizing the likelihood function in the case of Gaussian distributed errors' ([this is how Gauss described the Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#History)).

The likelihood function for Gaussian distributed errors is the joint distribution for the measurements $y_i$:

$$\mathcal{L}(a,b,c ; y_i, x_i) = f(y_i ; a,b,c, x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{y_i-f(x_i,a,b,c)}{\sigma} \right)^2} $$

Where $f(x_i, a, b , c)$ is some function, which is not necessarily linear, that describes the model of $y_i$ as function of $x_i$ (you could say the mean of $y_i$ conditional on $x_i$) where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are model parameters that can be changed to optimize the likelihood. The expression $y_i - f(x_i, a, b, c)$ is the residual/error term.

When you take the logarithm of this expression then the relationship with the least squares method becomes clear.

$$\begin{array}{rcl} \log \mathcal{L}(a,b,c ; y_i, x_i) &=& \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{y_i-f(x_i,a,b,c)}{\sigma} \right)^2} \right)\\
 &=& - \frac{n}{2} \log \left( 2\pi\sigma^2 \right) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \underbrace{ \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_i-f(x_i,a,b,c) \right)^2}_{ \text{sum of squares term}}
\end{array}$$

---

#### Finding the MLE for different error distributions

Using [`optim`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html), a general purpose optimization function, you could optimize a likelihood function defined by yourself (which may not need to be sum of least squares and based on Gaussian distributed errors) in order to tackle different types of error distributions.

Possibly easier is to apply weights to the residuals and use minimized least squares as an approximation to some other likelihood function. This can be done with for instance [`gnls`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/gnls.html) a function to fit non-linear functions with the [generalized least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares) method.

---

#### In your case least squares is sufficient.

I think you should not need to go trough these troubles. You do have  some correlation between residuals but the residual term is only small anyway and your function seems to fit well enough. Estimates of confidence intervals based on log likelihood may be corrupt though (but they are not exact estimates anyway).

[image: it fits well enough]

A contrasting example is here: [Understanding Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) and its confidence intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/363551/)  This is an example where the data is only 0's and 1's and it is useful to use a special likelihood function and solve the MLE instead of using the least squares method.