# Understanding Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) and its confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, nonlinear-regression, probit

I'm trying to figure out if I am actually understanding MLE correctly, or at least applying it correctly to my data. My data consists of several patients for which I have some data, which is used in the following equations.

My problem is to find the best fit parameters (three) of a model through MLE for my data. And from what I can read in literature, for my type of example, the log-likelihood function is this:

$$ LLH (D_{50}, m, n) = \sum\limits_{y(i)=1}\log(NTCP(D_{50}, m, n)) + \sum\limits_{y(i)=0}\log(1- NTCP(D_{50}, m, n)) $$

Where ´NTCP`and`t` is given by:

$$ NTCP = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{t} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx$$

$$ t = \frac{gEUD - D_{50}}{m\times D_{50}}$$

$D_{50}$ can be values from 0 to in principle infinite. However, it is most likely that the optimal parameter would be in the range of 0-150. $m$ is probably in the range of 0-3, and $gEUD$ is calculated from the equation below.

$$ gEUD = \left(\sum\limits_{i} v_i d_{i}^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n} $$
As stated, I have several patients, and for each patient I have a two column list with values that is used for the $v_i$ and $d_i$ in the above equation to get the $gEUD$. Each patient is also associated with a value of 1 or 0, which tells me if this patient has had any toxicity from treatment (1 = yes, 0 = no). In turn, this is used in the $LLH$ function to divide patients into either one of the sums or the other.

So what I have done so far is to calculate the NTCP (as seen in the equation, which happens to be a sigmoid function given by `scipy.stats.norm(0, 1).cdf(t)` in python, where `t` has all the parameters) for all patients. I then create a grid of parameters `(D50, m, and n)`, let's say a `(100, 100, 100)` grid, which means 1 million calculated NTCP values for each patient (different parameters lead to different NTCPs). So in my case, the NTCP can take values such as 1 or 0 (0% to 100% probability of getting toxicity), which means that in the cases where I have log(0) I will have infinity. So in my python code I check for 0's or 1's in all 1 million calculations for each patient, and combine these indexes (of 0's and 1's) and remove it from the parameter grid for all patients. So in turn I am losing some parameter sets since they won't be calculated otherwise.
After that I take index `(0, 0, 0)` for all patients, and divide them accordingly to the LLH equation (y(i) = 1 if they have toxicity, or y(0) = 0 if they don't), and then get a LLH for that one parameter set. And this is obviously done for the entire grid for all patients, and I end up with approximately 1 million LLH values (minus the ones that has been removed due to the possible log(0)). I then find the maximum value, and that is supposed to be my MLE, right ?

I have no idea if there is an built-in python function/package that can do this, but nonetheless, I have written this my self. Obviously it takes some time calculating 1 million vales for x-number of patients, but I guess that is how it is.

My problem is, however, that I have data where the least square method has been used to find the best fitted parameters, and if I do this MLE method on the same data, I don't quite get the same result. Should that worry me, or...?

Also, for finding confidence intervals I have read that profile log likelihood should be the way to go, but also bootstrapping. What would be recommended in my case if I actually end up with a list of approximately 1 million LLH values ?

Comment: I am confused: what exactly are the parameters that you want to maximize over? So far what you have written is a fixed expression with a bogous 't' in there. Could you provide a reference to the description of the model in the literature? Also: What exactly do you mean by 't contains all the parameters'? I am especially puzzled about the fact that you have a cdf in there and not a density (because if this indeed is log likelihood then exp(your expression) should be a density!).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my OP with another figure of the equations used for calculating `t` in the error function. So basically D50 and m are just the values they are for each calculation, whereas n is used to calculate another thing (EUD) that is going to be different for each patient. So when putting all parameters (one set at a time) to use you can then calculate the NTCP (i.e. the expression with the bogus `t`). This NTCP is then used in the LLH equation, again for all parameter sets in the grid, where I then take the log of each individual NTCP and sum through the patients

Comment: So summarized: $D_50, m, n$ are the parameters and you want to find $D_50, m, n$ such that the expression above becomes maximal, yes? Are $D_50, m, n$ supposed to come from a certain range or are these just real numbers? In the latter case you could try to do that in an analytical exact manner by exlicitly finding a point where the gradient becomes zero. That would be the optimal solution. It seems involved at first but you probably need to compute the gradient in any case for applying numeric methods (gradient ascend) if that first approach does not work. But I guess that m, n have to be...

Comment: integers, is that right?

Comment: Not integers no, unfortunately. The range of D50 is around 0-150 (in reality I would like in steps of 0.1), n can take values from 0 to 1, and m is also in the small range from 0-2 or 3.

Comment: There is lot's to read before the actual question turns up and along the road all kinds of terms pop up that I do not get. For instance in $$gEUD = \left(\sum\limits_{i} v_i d_{i}^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n}$$

what does $gEUD$ mean? what are $n$ $v_i$ and $d_i$, how does this relate to the data that you start your post with?

Comment: But can they take an arbitrary value (like, are they supposed to be in an interval of the reals or can they only come from a discrete set)? If these are (bounded) arbitrary values then you can use concepts like derivatives in order to optimize that numerically.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings so I could in principle explain much more, but I thought it might get a bit long if I did, therefore I just tried with the equations themselves. So basically gEUD is a type of converted dose (radiation dose) that needs to be calculated for each patient. The vi and di are values that I have in a two column list for each patient that is used, together with n, to calculate one values, i.e. gEUD.

Comment: @FabianWerner They can indeed be arbitrary (if I understand you correctly). I just know beforehand what the range of the values should be within. But if it's in steps of 0.1 or 0.0000001 doesn't matter really. In my case (the way I have done it for now) it just takes much computation time the smaller steps I want to check (i.e. the search grid gets larger).

Comment: Then I suggest that you do three things: 1) come up with a measurement how good the model works (i.e. other than MLE) 2) compute the gradient 3) use a general optimization procedure like 'minimize' with parameter method='BFGS' in the package scipy.optimize and provide the function and gradient as a parameter to this function. If this takes too long then use only a small randomly selected portion of the training data and use the other part and 1) to evaluate when you have used 'enought' training data.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I have now tried to reduce/change a bit. I'm not sure if that helps ? The basic idea of the question was to get a read of the whether the way I'm currently performing my MLE is just pure wrong or on the right track at least.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Basically yes.

Comment: Maybe you could write $v_{ij}$ and $d_{ij}$. The subscript $i$ is already used for patients in your first formula when you use $y_{(i)}$ and this is confusing when you use the same subscript for $v$ and $d$ (which, I guess, are multiple measurements $j$ within the same patient $i$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer to all your various questions but it does help you to get further with your model.

#### Probit model

What you are describing

$\log \mathcal{L}(D_{50},m,n|y_i) =  \sum\limits_{y(i)=1}\log(P(D_{50}, m, n)) + \sum\limits_{y(i)=0}\log(1- P(D_{50}, m, n))$

is a probit model.

Note that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^t e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx = \Phi(t)$$

is the cumulative distribution function of standard normal distribution.

Your loglikelihood model corresponds to a Bernouilli distribution for each individual $Y_i$:

$$P(Y_i=1|t_i) = 1 - P(Y_i=1|t_i) = \Phi(t_i) $$

---

#### Faster estimation method by solving linear part seperately

Note that if you keep $n$ fixed then the parameter $t$ is basically linear:

$$t_i = \frac{x_i - D_{50}}{mD_{50}}  = ax_i + b$$

where $x_i = gEUD_i(n)$, $a = \frac{1}{mD_{50}}$, $b = -\frac{1}{m}$.

Now you can put your model in a very standard (GLM) form for which many solution methods (and standard software) exists:

$$P(Y_i=1|t_i) = 1 - P(Y_i=1|t_i) = \Phi(ax_i + b) $$

and

$$f(y_i|x_i) = y_i \Phi(ax_i + b) + (1-y_i) (1-\Phi(ax_i + b))$$

then find which $n$, $a$ and $b$ maximize the likelihood function and you can compute your estimates for $m$ and $D_{50}$ from the estimates for $a$ and $b$.

This (only a grid search for $n$) is a faster solution method for the MLE than solving on a 100x100x100 grid.

---

- **I then find the maximum value, and that is supposed to be my MLE, right ?**
  Your grid search is valid (if you keep in mind that you check whether the maximum is not on the edge of the grid) but not very fast and scalable.

  Possibly you could use a non-linear optimization method to solve the model without a grid search. I do not know about such methods that are specialized for probit models.
- **I have data where the least square method has been used to find the best fitted parameters, and if I do this MLE method on the same data, I don't quite get the same result.**

  It is different to say exactly what is wrong when not knowing the details about the data and the least squares method. But it is *very* reasonable to expect that the MLE method which you use is gonna be different from least squares. With a probit model you assume that the data is distributed according to a Bernouilli distribution with a least squares model you assume that the data is distributed according to a Gaussian distribution, they are different things and particularly the Gaussian distribution (which does not model discrete values 0 or 1) is not very logical/correct to use and likely deviates from your results with a probit model.
- **for finding confidence intervals ... profile log likelihood ... but also bootstrapping. What would be recommended**

  Both methods are not gonna give an *exact* solution and this will be a matter about how you prefer to choose between pro's and con's

  The profile likelihood is approximately correct near the MLE and is gonna do better when the interval is not too far away from the center, as well when the interaction between the parameters is not to much. You can verify this on plots of the profiles.

  The bootstrapping is neither correct but you can make it as close to the correct CI as you wish given enough computation and time (so the question here is how much time and computer power do you have)

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I haven't thought about just reducing it to an 1D grid (n) instead of a 3D 100x100x100. I will try to see if I can incorporate that into my code, because it is indeed a time consuming process now, especially when doing it on a local computer. I do however have two questions if I may? 1) In my current grid search there are indeed probabilities that give 1 or 0 for some parameter sets. Is it correctly to assume, that in the case of the log() returning inf I should discard that parameter set all together, or...? 2) If bootstrapping and profile does not yield exact

Comment: solutions, is there another way of doing it, or is that just how it is ? That you get an interval that is justifiable, and you have to work with that.

Comment: I imagine that you get those 0's (bad predictions) because you are far away from the optimal MLE and the likelihood goes very much down to 0. You could verify this with a plot where you mark those occurrences of zero. The 1's may occur if your $y_i=1$ and $y_i=0$ cases are very much separated. Then your model will fit the parameters such that all the probabilities for those parameters go very close to 1.

Comment: If you have some code where you use a custom made function for optimization then you could use functions that compute the logarithms of functions (your formula involves the error function) more efficiently. That is, directly rather than in two steps (1: first compute the function and 2: use that function output as input for the logarithm). In that case you will get less cases of 1's and 0's.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. One last thing. For the solution to the linear regression you say that the x-values of the problem should be the $gEUD$ for each patients, with a fixed $n$. But what about the "y part". Have I stared myself blind on this, or...? Because $t_i$, which seems to be the y-values, well, that is calculated from the parameters I am trying to find, right ? I don't have values for that I can plot and optimize against the x-values (that's the way I'm seeing it now). So am I missing something here, or...?

Comment: Or is the toxicity (1 or 0) supposed to be the y-values for this ?

Comment: Yes the y values are the toxicity 1 or 0 values.

Comment: So it basically comes down to finding/writing software/packages that optimizes this equation: $f(y_i|x_i) = y_i \Phi(ax_i + b) + (1-y_i) (1-\Phi(ax_i + b))$ for every $x_i$ and $y_i$ ? I'm just not sure I understand how that would work. Usually when you do a regression fit you have x-values and y-values some what following a trend. In this case I will have several different x-values, but the y-values will change from 1 to 0. Will that not be a weird fit if there isn't much variance in the y-values ?

Comment: You will be doing a generalized linear model ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model ). Find software and information about that.

Comment: The typical linear regression treats the parameter $y$ as a normal distributed variable around some mean that is a linear function of $x$ (instead of $y_i = x_i + \epsilon_i$ with $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ you could also say $y_i \sim N(x_i,\sigma^2)$). With general linear models you have that (1) this distribution can be different (e.g. non continuous like a Bernoulli distributed variable), more specific it is an particular group of distributions from the exponential family (2) the linear function of $x$ can be wrapped inside a nonlinear function (in this case the function $\Phi(.)$